# How to group objects into one object in underscore

Tags: javascript, arrays, underscore.js

How to convert this :

```
[
  {name: 'foo', type: 'product'},
  {name: 'bar', type: 'product'},
  {name: 'john', type: 'product'},
  {name: 'no name', type: 'product'},
]
```

How can i group and get all the objects without name:'no name' as separate Object like this:

```
{  
  0:[
    {name: 'foo', type: 'product'},
    {name: 'bar', type: 'product'},
    {name: 'john', type: 'product'}
  ],

  1:[
    {name: 'no name', type: 'product'},
  ]
}
```

Comment: Your original post mixed array (`[ ]`) and object (`{ }`) literal syntax. I edited because I thought you meant an array, but now I am not so sure. Are you expecting an object with keys `0` and `1`, or an actual array? Or doesn't it matter?

Comment: i'm expecting an object with keys 0 with all names and 1:with 'no name'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To produce an object with keys `0` and `1`, use [`_.groupBy`](http://underscorejs.org/#groupBy):

```
var objectResult = _.groupBy(data, function(d) { return +(d.name === "no name")  })
```

To produce an array with two elements (which will also have keys `0` and `1`) you could use [`_.partition`](http://underscorejs.org/#partition) (Underscore 1.6.0 +):

> `partition_.partition(array, predicate)`:  Split array into two arrays:
>   one whose elements all satisfy predicate and one whose elements all do
>   not satisfy predicate.

```
var arrayResult = _.partition(data, function(d) { return d.name !== "no name"  })
```

[JSBin](http://jsbin.com/ruduya/edit?js,console)

Answer (score 1):

As a comparison, plain ECMAScript takes just a little more code:

```
data.reduce(function(acc, obj) {
  acc[obj.name == 'no name'? 1:0].push(obj);
  return acc;},{0:[],1:[]}
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try http://underscorejs.org/#groupBy:

```
var data = [
  {name: 'foo', type: 'product'},
  {name: 'bar', type: 'product'},
  {name: 'john', type: 'product'},
  {name: 'no name', type: 'product'},
]

var results = _.groupBy(data, function(obj) { return obj.name == 'no name' ? 1 : 0; })

console.log(results)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like that.

```
var arr = [
 {name: 'foo', type: 'product'},
 {name: 'bar', type: 'product'},
 {name: 'john', type: 'product'},
 {name: 'no name', type: 'product'},
];

var result = _.groupBy(arr, function (elem) { 
 return elem.name == 'no name' ? 1: 0;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Why use a framework for such a simple thing ?
Here is a pure JS solution allowing to groupBy properly.
It is then easy to work with the result object.

```
var array=[
  {name: 'foo', type: 'product'},
  {name: 'bar', type: 'product'},
  {name: 'john', type: 'product'},
  {name: 'no name', type: 'product'},
  {name: 'foo', type: 'product'},
  {name: 'bar', type: 'product'},
  {name: 'john', type: 'product'},
  {name: 'no name', type: 'product'},
  {name: 'no name', type: 'product'},
  {name: 'no name', type: 'product'},
  {name: 'no name', type: 'product'},
];        

function groupBy(propertyName, array) {
var groupedElements = {};
for (var i = 0, len = array.length; i < len; i++) {
    var el = array[i];
    var value = el[propertyName].trim();
    var group = groupedElements[value];
    if (group === undefined) {
        group = [el];
        groupedElements[value] = group;
    } else {
        group.push(el);
    }
}
return groupedElements;
}

var result = groupBy('name',array);
```

Comment: I understand the sentiment, but I think there are some good reasons. For example, 1. the library version uses less code; 2. the logic in underscore has been rigorously tested and improved over years; 3. a lot of projects are already using a library like underscore so there's little extra cost.

Comment: This doesn't quite answer the question, since it does not group together all of the objects with `name !== "no name"`.

Comment: it does answer the question. I understand some needs to use frameworks instead of trying to learn how things run. I only code in pure js and sometimes jquery. All those frameworks are totally useless anyway.

Comment: It outputs an Object with four keys; the question is asking for two.

Comment: Ot s even better ! Dont you think ?